# Display method Customer Name

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have created a new table with different fields, 1 of them is `CustAccount`, in the form i want to create a column next of `CustAccount` showing the `CustName`.

I want to `display` the Customer Name, based on the selection of the CustAccount.

I have tried using the existing method `name`on the table `CustTable`, which contains the following code:

```
display CustName name()
{
    DirPartyTable   dirPartyTable;
    CustName        custName;
    boolean         isSet = false;

    try
    {
        if (this.hasRelatedTable(identifierStr(DirPartyTable_FK)))
        {
            dirPartyTable = this.relatedTable(identifierStr(DirPartyTable_FK)) as DirPartyTable;

            //Check to make sure the fields we are accessing are selected.
            if (dirPartyTable && dirPartyTable.isFieldDataRetrieved(fieldStr(DirPartyTable, Name)))
            {
                custName = dirPartyTable.Name;
                isSet = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception::Error)
    {
        isSet = false;
    }

    //If we aren't joined to DirPartyTable or it isn't selected, then do a query to get it.
    if(!isSet)
    {
        custName = DirPartyTable::getName(this.Party);
    }

    return custName;
}
```

This displays a customer name, except not based on the CustAccount selection. I am thinking about copying the code to a new method on my new table. How do I edit the code to accomplish this?

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to copy that method to your table.  Instead refer to it by putting this method on your table:

```
// BP deviation documented
display CustName name()
{
    return CustTable::find(this.CustAcccount).name();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this method `Name()` work fine. Also are others ways.

I leave two ways to get what you want:

```
CustTable     CustTable;
AccountNum    pCust;
str           cName;            
DirPartyTable DirPartyTable;

;

//First option     
pCust = "YourCustomer";    
Select * from CustTable where CustTable.AccountNum == pCust;
cName = CustTable.name(); //Get Name
//First option END

//Second option
pCust = "YourCustomer";    
Select Party from CustTable where CustTable.AccountNum == pCust
    join DirPartyTable where DirPartyTable.RecId == CustTable.Party;
cName = DirPartyTable.Name; //Get Name
//Second option END
```

Comment: Why do you use the `SqlParameters` table to store the value for the `AccountNum` criteria?

Comment: Hi, because if yo use a simple str variable you get a runtime error. Regards.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use the `AccountNum` extended data type to define the variable instead of an arbitrary table field? Or use `str [20] pCust;`?

Comment: Perhaps. The solution is the same, If you like more use `AccountNum` Extended data type It is also correct. but if you declare a variable like that `str [20] pCust;` you get a error. **_Syntax error_**.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was writing from memory and got it mixed up with an array declaration. The second part should be `str 20 pCust;` without the brackets. My point is that while all three solutions work, the one with the `AccountNum` extended data type is my preferred one because it makes for the most clear and readable code. I would be very confused if I saw your solution in production code because I would be wondering why the `SqlParameters` table is used. There is just no connection to the rest of the code.

Comment: ok, if for most clear and readable code, yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Maybe you could change your answer as to not to confuse other readers?